# How to populate (mark checked) a checkedListBox with a StringCollection

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox

I have a checkedListBox with 10 Items in my Collection on my windows form.  Using C# VS210.

I am looking for a simple way to mark as checked only 2 of the items from my checkedListBox by using values stored in the Settings.Settings file, (stored as System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection).  I have not been able to find this example out there, I know I am supposed to use the CheckedListBox.CheckedItems Property somehow, but haven't found an example.

```
private void frmUserConfig_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string item in Properties.Settings.Default.checkedListBoxSystem)
    {
        checkedListBoxSystem.SetItemCheckState(item, CheckState.Checked);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using an [Extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)?

```
static class CheckedListBoxHelper
{
    public static void SetChecked(this CheckedListBox list, string value)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (list.Items[i].Equals(value))
            {
                list.SetItemChecked(i, true);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And slightly change the logic in your load event, like this:

```
private void frmUserConfig_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string item in Properties.Settings.Default.checkedListBoxSystem)
    {
        checkedListBoxSystem.SetChecked(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Deni,
That example worked wonderfully.  thank you for your reply.  I learned about Extension Methods as well.  Best, John.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of `SetItemCheckState` takes an index (int). Try to get the index of the item you want to check, and then use `SetItemCheckState` with the index to check it.